# Fibre washer size

Tags: plumbing, toilet, leak, valve

Morning all

Newbie here

I replaced my old ballcock valve in the toilet. The old one was about 25 years old and was dripping with water slowly coming out of the overflow valve.
The cistern is a side filler and it seems that once I undid the nut on the pipe which connects to the cistern, there apparently was a small fabric washer inside that I lost.

Does anyone know what size this fabric washer is so I can obtain a new one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you measure the fitting internal and external diameter where the washer goes to be able to find one, the thickness will probably be between 1/16 and 1/8".

Comment: If it's on the small pipe from the fill valve to the shutoff valve, I'd just replace that pipe/flexible  fitting. Finding an exact fit will be harder than getting a new pipe.

Comment: Thanks for your help Guys, I've managed to sort it as it was an half inch fabric washer so problem solved.